# Silverlight PrintDocument Timeout Issues

Tags: .net, silverlight, printing

I'm having a problem trying to print from Silverlight.  The issue is that I'm printing out several pages of images but the source I have to pull them back from is not incredibly fast and it sometimes takes longer to create the page than the 8 tries that PrintPage makes before failing.

Is there a way to make it try more than 8 times extend the amount of time between tries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can prepare all the necessary data and caching them on the client side before printing.

Also, you can block the thread in the PrintPage event while you wait for the next image to prepare (Not a good idea ...).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Unfortunately, we are talking about lots of images and I'm very worried about memory usage in the client system.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe, you can use an IsolatedStorage for cache?

Comment: Ended up going a whole different route, inspired by your comment about prepping all the necessary data.  Instead of requesting an image at a time, I'm sending a list of images, formatting that all in a pdf and then returning the pdf.