# Printing with Silverlight and asynchronous loads

Tags: silverlight, printing

For security reasons printing a document with Silverlight can only be done when a user press a button.
If I try to print a document that needs to load resources, like images, from the server and the loading time is too high then the document printing fails.

Is there a way/an option allowing to increase the time of preparation for a document to print ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902057/silverlight-printdocument-timeout-issues. Have you considered creating a PDF on the server and returning that to the client/browser? That is what I would typically do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried it already, and the problem is the same. Most of the time loading the PDF will take too much time, and printing will fail.

Comment: Not quite sure still how you are doing this when you say the "printing will fail" in that you aren't really printing directly going this route, just downloading a PDF that the user would have to view and then print from the PDF viewer (Adobe or whatever). Maybe a few more details on what you are actually trying to do would help.

Comment: I want a simple solution for the user, Printing a PDF from another program is not an option.